# summarize() warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, summarize

I am trying to find the mean by year in my data using dplyr. I can't figure out why may code gives me NAs. Here is my code:

```
S1b$Loans.and.discounts <- gsub(",","",S1b$Loans.and.discounts)
S1b$Loans.and.discounts <- as.numeric(S1b$Loans.and.discounts)
S1b <- S1b %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize(loans_discounts=mean(county_panel$Loans.and.discounts, na.rm=T))
```

It gives me a number of the following warning message:

"In mean.default(county_panel$Loans.and.discounts, na.rm = T) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Yet is.numeric(S1b$Loans.and.discounts) comes back TRUE. I am sure I made a simple mistake but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

Here are the first 6 lines of my data:

```
        S1b <- structure(list(yearid = c("BARBOURAlabamaEastern Bank of AlabamaEufaula AL United States1859", 
"DALLASAlabamaBank of SelmaSelma AL United States1860", "DALLASAlabamaBank of SelmaSelma AL United States1861", 
"DALLASAlabamaCommercial Bank of AlabamaSelma AL United States1858", 
"DALLASAlabamaCommercial Bank of AlabamaSelma AL United States1858", 
"DALLASAlabamaCommercial Bank of AlabamaSelma AL United States1859"
), Loans.and.discounts = structure(c(2L, 76L, 79L, 105L, 126L, 
10L), .Label = c("1,036,732.32", "1,046,344.00", "1,059,448.00", 
"1,064,412.02", "1,123,057.00", "1,134,057.08", "1,203,749.19", 
"1,261,178.00", "1,267,007.00", "1,294,503.00", "1,371,251.00", 
"1,382,316.00", "1,428,948.03", "1,430,751.00", "1,435,369.00", 
"1,442,768.40", "1,478,016.00", "1,500,152.00", "1,566,613.00", 
"1,586,888.00", "1,686,925.00", "1,688,333.02", "1,710,964.00", 
"1,735,238.22", "1,736,139.00", "1,744,934.00", "1,799,224.00", 
"1,828,353.31", "1,833,584.00", "1,855,272.00", "1,877,776.00", 
"1,890,808.80", "1,893,964.00", "1,909,825.20", "1,922,956.00", 
"1,952,375.00", "1,956,057.00", "1,994,781.03", "1,996,300.00", 
"139,215.00", "2,025,011.00", "2,065,108.45", "2,082,529.00", 
"2,127,799.00", "2,141,789.00", "2,142,311.00", "2,186,245.00", 
"2,205,359.00", "2,207,533.10", "2,224,840.80", "2,240,610.00", 
"2,273,343.69", "2,273,427.69", "2,303,140.00", "2,345,513.31", 
"2,370,536.96", "2,374,253.31", "2,380,343.00", "2,385,165.00", 
"2,511,346.00", "2,517,237.85", "2,567,402.00", "2,570,795.00", 
"2,603,449.00", "2,681,028.00", "2,733,045.89", "2,806,416.00", 
"2,818,021.93", "2,845,855.00", "2,936,997.00", "2,943,118.89", 
"2,951,269.00", "2,967,790.77", "2,971,323.00", "201,897.00", 
"208,991.00", "255,312.00", "256,858.00", "295,836.00", "3,009,071.95", 
"3,015,990.00", "3,083,618.00", "3,102,461.35", "3,135,833.35", 
"3,169,470.00", "3,265,545.00", "3,273,119.00", "3,280,694.00", 
"3,349,759.00", "3,407,438.86", "3,433,263.04", "3,596,460.00", 
"3,720,258.00", "3,748,473.00", "3,781,071.00", "3,999,250.00", 
"312,625.00", "329,828.00", "330,726.00", "337,915.00", "359,461.00", 
"371,394.00", "398,448.00", "4,147,912.19", "446,867.00", "5,141,469.23", 
"5,284,763.00", "5,409,653.65", "5,953,621.00", "554,726.00", 
"558,114.00", "6,026,826.00", "6,285,744.15", "6,603,403.00", 
"6,681,923.12", "600,810.00", "602,110.00", "605,939.00", "7,116,768.83", 
"7,275,751.36", "72,117.60", "783,223.00", "8,088,453.00", "8,175,581.00", 
"883,968.03", "988,263.00", "99,324.36"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(30L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 29L, 30L), .Label = c("1830", 
    "1831", "1832", "1833", "1834", "1835", "1836", "1837", "1838", 
    "1839", "1840", "1841", "1842", "1843", "1844", "1845", "1846", 
    "1847", "1848", "1849", "1850", "1851", "1852", "1853", "1854", 
    "1855", "1856", "1857", "1858", "1859", "1860", "1861"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1128L, 
6505L, 6517L, 6865L, 6876L, 6888L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
S1b <- S1b %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
summarize(loans_discounts=mean(county_panel$Loans.and.discounts, na.rm=T))
```

to

```
S1b <- S1b %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
summarize(loans_discounts=mean(Loans.and.discounts, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: This looks correct and just like the answer I was about to post `county_panel$` should not be in there

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Thanks! stupid mistake.

Comment: @LouisEcon nice! Make sure to accept the answer by Robert Wilson above (click the check-mark to the left of his answer under the up/down arrows)